# Google recaptcha v3 and still able to send spam request

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using Google recaptcha v3 in my site by following official guideline.

but when i opened Browser Console and write the following code

```js
function flood(){
    var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    var string = '';
    for(var ii=0; ii<15; ii++){
        string += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    email = document.getElementById("email");
    email.value = string+"@gmail.com";
    $("#submitBtn").trigger("click");
}
setInterval(flood, 1000);
```

Here you can see in image preview about 37 spam requests sent to server successfully.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou72F.png)

Anyway to avoid this?
Thanks

Follwoing JavaScript code i use in frontend.

```js
$('#newsletterForm').submit(function(event) {
        $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#ajax-response").fadeIn();
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
  
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('6LfX1N4bAAAAABRp1LK3Io5u8pq7xn9iYqiXioru', {action: 'process'}).then(function(token) {
                $('#newsletterForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
                $('#newsletterForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="process">');
                //$('#newsletterForm').unbind('submit').submit();
                $.post("./process.php", {
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    token: $("#token").val(),
                    action: $("#action").val()
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#message").text(response);
                    $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", false)
                    $("#ajax-response").fadeIn();
                })
            });;
        });
  });
```

and backend in php

```php
 // other code...
    
    // use the reCAPTCHA PHP client library for validation
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY);
    $resp = $recaptcha->setExpectedAction($action)
                    ->setScoreThreshold(0.5)
                    ->verify($token, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                    
        if ($resp->isSuccess()) {  // success process   }     
else {// spam request}
```

Comment: Please read this https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-google-recaptcha-v3-in-php-contact-form article, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misunderstood the concept... You can never prevent people to send requests to your server with javascript code... You have to always check on the server side too... That's why you are using reCaptcha like solutions. This makes sure that the request comes from your original site / frontend using reCaptcha with a valid token... If it's not valid you won't be doing any "source expensive" operations on the serverside.

Comment: In many websites i see the title "confirm you're not a bot"
so the code i write are bot not an actual human!